# window:afterprint not working after window.print() in Angular

Tags: angular, window

I am opening window.print() on a button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="printDocument()"> Print </button>
```

on that printDocument method, I opened the doc in a new window and called window.print().

```
printDocument() {
    let str = `<embed src="https://beta.lottoweaver.com/WeaverDoc/commonContent/www.nationallottery.co.za/playerDocument/408466_ID_PROOF_null_1614276509176.jpg" width='100%' height="100%">`;

    this.OpenWindow = window.open("","","width=900, height=600, left=200, top=100");
    this.OpenWindow.document.body.innerHTML = str;
    this.OpenWindow.print();
  }
```

Now, after the user cancels or print the document, I want to close the window so I tried it with `@HostListener`

```
@HostListener("window:afterprint", ["$event"])
  onafterPrint(event) {
    this.OpenWindow.close();
  }
```

But this event is never called when I cancel or save from the print window.

How should I close the window after print window is closed?

Here is a working stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tnxv4w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, by opening a print window:

```
<div [id]="'print-section'">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor eius error expedita nam natus, nulla veritatis? Consequuntur corporis, delectus ducimus eaque eius, eos, magnam molestias omnis quaerat quidem rem soluta.
</div>



print(): void {
    const printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    const popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Print Page</title>
            </head>
            <body
                style="font-size: 14px;
                    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue',
                    Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    color: #333";
                onload="document.execCommand('print');window.close()">${printContents}</body>
        </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: This closes the window as soon as it is opened

Comment: It seems window.print isn't working on latest chrome browser https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/16251503?hl=en

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if it works!

Comment: I tried with updated answer.. The window is still closing as soon as it is opened.. @Mohiuddin

Comment: comment out last line "popupWin.document.close();" and check what happens,
it works fine on my local machine..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution down below depends on *matchMedia*:

1. in *AppComponent* decalre this function:

```
  media(query: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia(query);
    return fromEvent<MediaQueryList>(mediaQuery, 'change').pipe(
      startWith(mediaQuery),
      map((list: MediaQueryList) => list.matches)
    );
  }
```

this function will return true or false when the parameter you passed  match the window media.

2. inside `ngOnInit` subscribe this fucntion with `pairwise` operator and pass 'print' to matchMedia print
   `this.media('print').pipe(pairwise())`

> ***Note***: we need pairwise operator to check when print and after print
> when print dialog opened so the value will be true and after print dialog closed the value will be false

3. 

```
 this.media('print').pipe(pairwise()).subscribe(([print,notPrint]) =>{
      // check afterprint that refers to the print dialog opened and then closed
      if(print && !notPrint){
        /* but you code here */
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work fine !

**.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="printDocument()"> Print 
</button>
```

**.ts**

```
 printDocument() {
          let str = `<embed src="https://beta.lottoweaver.com/WeaverDoc/commonContent/www.nationallottery.co.za/playerDocument/408466_ID_PROOF_null_1614276509176.jpg" width='100%' height="100%">`;
this.OpenWindow = window.open(
  "",
  "_blank",
  "width=900, height=600, left=200, top=100"
);

this.OpenWindow.document.write(
  `<html>
        <head>
            <title>Hello Print</title>
        </head>
        <body onafterprint="window.close()"">`+str+`</body>
    </html>
    `
);

this.OpenWindow.print();
  }
```

[this is demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgoyer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It is working fine on the demo link but on my local machine, the window is closing as soon as it is opened. I'm using Angular 7.

Comment: @Nehal it's also working fine on my local device ! with angular 5,6,7